# Do you avoid the damage if you kill a turret right before its missile hits you?

Tags: league-of-legends

This has happened to me various times but its kinda fuzzy as I can't find anything official on it.

Lets say you tank a turret with a teammate so you think you're gonna kill the turret in time before you die but then you realize you won't make it in time so you decide to run away or even flash out if the timing of the game is crucial and you really don't want to die. You are only one hit and right before you flash the turret fires a missile which of course follows you to wherever you flashed. But before the missile lands on you and kills you, your teammate manages to kill the turret and when the missile hits you it makes no damage.

Now the same of course has happened to me with champion skills. For example I've killed a leblanc but she had already thrown her Q on me and it killed me even though it landed after she died. Or a nunu snowball or any other locked spell with a short delay.

I'm pretty certain you can't get damage from turrets if they get destroyed in the meantime but as I said I can't find anything official. 
Can someone confirm this or point to a link stating it?
I've always wondered :)

[Here is the wiki about turrets where nothing related is mentioned.](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Turret)

EDIT: I'll use a picture to make it even more clear. If the turret in the picture was destroyed at that exact moment blitzcrank would take no damage from the purple missile heading towards him :)
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, If the missle has been shot, you will take the damage no matter if the turret is there or not.

A shot that acts like a guided missle can not be avoided.
Only shots that are not guided can be avoided by stepping or flashing aside.

The turret has a Guided missile system. So that means it will hit you and damage you no matter what you do.

It shouldn't be too easy after all.

A turret is there to give protection. Not to be dodged by every attacker.

Comment: This is true. I've recalled in front of a tower while my minion wave was taking it down. At the last second, the tower targeted me and fired. The tower projectile followed me all the way back to the fountain and damaged me even though a new minion wave had destroyed the tower while the projectile was en-route.

Comment: I will definitely do some tests on this as I'm absolutely certain that it has happened to me (not taking dmg) more than 5 times. Maybe it was a bug that they fixed.. But still it's interesting. I know how the missile system works though and you guys are right that it SHOULD be like this (and maybe it is now).

Comment: @PanagiotisPalladinos Its overall knowledgeable since a tower is there to defend the place... not to be taken easy. It was a bug in the past but it was fixed a while ago. People could dodge the last bullet when tower died. But it changed to "When its shot, It will hit.".

Comment: @Ladineko so that means you had seen it too..? Cause I'm with you there. I agree that the turret should and is probably hitting you. I just wanted to know if such a bug existed and maybe when they fixed it. I haven't been able to find any Official Patch Notes about it.

Comment: @PanagiotisPalladinos Yes it was a bug. It might be somewhere in the patch notes during a big update i think, cant remember when. But at this moment it has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The shots already been fired. Just like how skill shot will still hit for a short time after the champions dies, the turret's shot will still go for you.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to avoid taking damage would be to become invincible right before the attack hit. Otherwise you will be hit and take damage