# Can you make a turret change targets?

Tags: league-of-legends

I guess you can't but I'm not quite sure. Say it attacks an ally at low health and they can't get out of range in time, is there any way to make the turret hit you instead (if no minions are around)?

Answer (score 2):

Once a target has been acquired, a turret doesn't change targets until its current one is dead. This is precisely what allows for turret tanking to be viable.

There is an item called [Ohmwrecker](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ohmwrecker) which stops a turret from attacking for 3 seconds.

Comment: There is a support item that can be used that stops turrets from being able to fire for 2.5 seconds. Don't remember what it is called but its pretty much the only way to save someone in this kind of situation(short of killing the turret before the shot connects)

Comment: There is also a soft lock on and a hard lock on. The soft lock on is when it picks the next target to attack when all enemy minions within range have been killed. Soft lockons can be switched to another champion by dealing damage to an enemy champion within the turrets protective area. Hard lock ons are when the turret locks onto an enemy champion after they deal damage to a champion on the turrets team. This cannot be broken short of out ranging the turret or the two methods I listed above.

Comment: @Ravekner If the projectile is already in the air, it will do damage even if you kill the turret before it hits you. I learned this the hard way :(

Comment: @Schism I'm fairly certain that if the turret is destroyed before the animation for the attack connects with your champion, the damage is not registered. I may be wrong. Would need to test this though as either instance could be easily misunderstood if it wasn't recorded and watched at a time when you weren't worried about everything else that is happening in the game at the time.

Comment: @Ravekner I know because I've been executed by a turret after we destroyed it. (There were no minions around at the time.) :P

Comment: @Ravekner I think one the shot is fired damage in imminent, I think there is even a question and awnser talking about it but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @Ravekner http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/103388/do-you-avoid-the-damage-if-you-kill-a-turret-right-before-its-missile-hits-you - Check my question above. We have concluded that its not possible to "avoid" getting hit once the projectile is locked. Nevertheless I am still pretty sure that what you describe is a bug that still happens if the projectile JUST went off (and is not mid flight or something). It has happened to me many times.

Comment: @PanagiotisPalladinos That is the one :p

Comment: That makes sense to me at least, thanks for the link.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! It's all clear now. I was blamed a couple times for not standing in front of an ally who was about to die to take the turret shots for them. I was 99% sure that's not how turrets work... You can't intercept the shot. But they didn't seem to believe it. I was beginning to think they knew something I didn't.

Answer (score 2):

> is there any way to make the turret hit you instead (if no minions are
>   around)

The only way to cause a turret to attack you is to damage an opponent's champion within range of the turret.  This will cause the turret to focus you instead.

You can cause the turret to quit attacking by using the item [Ohmwrecker](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ohmwrecker).

Anything that causes the target to become untargetable will force the turret to look for a new target.  [Zhonya's Hourglass](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Zhonya's_Hourglass), [Lissandra's Frozen Tomb](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Lissandra), [Leblanc's Mirror Image](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/LeBlanc), etc.

It may also be possible to shield or move an ally away from the turret, like with [Thresh's lantern](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Thresh).

Answer (score 1):

You can attack an enemy champion, but this will only work if your ally did not attack an enemy champion before you. Note that the enemy champion must also be within the turret's range.

As several others said, you can use the Ohmwrecker, which will make the tower stop shooting.

There are also abilities that the champion targeted by the turret can use. Abilities that make you disappear from the game for just a fraction of a second, such as Shaco's Hallucinate and Master Yi's Alpha Strike, will force the turret to change focus to another target.

Destroying the tower also works.  If you destroy a tower after it shoots but before the bolt hits the target, the target will not take any damage.

Answer (score 1):

The [wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Turret) page is pretty clear about this :

> Turrets will continue to attack their current target **until the target dies, leaves attack range, or becomes untargetable due to abilities or items**.
>
> If an enemy champion within range deals damage to an allied champion (including via damage over time or a pet), the turret **will change targets to that enemy champion unless the turret is already targeting another enemy champion**.

This can be exploited to force a turret to attack you by dealing the first bit of damage. But once it's done, you cannot undo it.